# SQLite don't work with two dates

Tags: sqlite, date, select, where-clause

I have a table:

```
create table snapshot_info (r_object_id text, 
date_snapshot date, 
version text,
ka_regnum_or_type text,
ka_registration_date date, 
ka_doc_kind text, 
ka_title text, 
ka_author_name text,
ka_addressee text,
ka_state_name_ru text,
ka_out_number text,
ka_visa_real_authors_s text,
 ka_type_object text) ;
```

with records in field date_snapshot

```
07.10.2013 10:56:58 | 
07.10.2013 10:58:23 | 
15.10.2013 01:00:42 | 
16.10.2013 14:54:33 | 
16.10.2013 23:12:23 | 
17.10.2013 11:12:36 | 
17.10.2013 10:43:47 | 
18.10.2013 10:19:36 |
```

If I run the query

```
select r_object_id, version from snapshot_info where date_snapshot >= CAST('02.01.2010 00:00:00' AS datetime);
```

I get all records, it's good
but if i run query with two date i can't get all records

```
select r_object_id, version from snapshot_info where date_snapshot >= CAST('02.01.2010 00:00:00' AS datetime) and date_snapshot < CAST('12.12.2013 00:00:00' AS datetime);
```

why? i'm use and BETWEEN and datetime() and date() but it doesn't work

Comment: i'm found answer use

    select r_object_id, version from snapshot_info where (CAST (date_snapshot AS datetime)>= CAST('02.01.2010 00:00:00' AS datetime) and CAST(date_snapshot AS datetime)<= CAST('29.10.2013 02:55:23'  AS datetime));

thanks

Comment: It's a miracle that is working. As @larrylusting said, "Your expression is not doing anything remotely like what you think it's doing"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression is not doing anything remotely like what you think it's doing.

There is no DATETIME data type in SQLite, so you're not casting to DATETIME, but rather to something else (Numeric or NONE).  When I try your cast:

```
 SELECT cast('12.12.2013 14:23:01' as datetime);
```

from the SQLite command line, I get 12.12.  That's being compared to the string values in your date_snapshot field and SQLite is returning the results.

Also, the date format you're using is not one that SQLite would be able to recognize even in it's date and time functions.

The best solution would be to use SQlite's "standard" string datetime representation (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) which, not coincidentally, can be used in these kinds of comparisons without casting or conversion of any kind.